# Configure default build options for DUB without affecting other build types

Tags: d, dub

If I define `"buildOptions": ["unittests"]` in the root of `dub.json`, I get unittests enabled for all builds, e.g. also for release builds. How can enable unittests only for the default build? I.e the build that is triggered by the command `dub`?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to `dub.json`:

```
"buildTypes": {
    "plain": {
        "buildOptions": ["unittests", "debugMode", "debugInfo"]
    },
}
```

Note that if this is a library and you release it, then unit tests will be enabled for your library if the library user builds their project with the `plain` configuration, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: It does not work. I'm using the latest DUB 0.9.24-rc.3, and DMD v2.068.0. Is it working for you? Can it be a bug?

Comment: @Tamas I've edited the `buildOptions` line, try it now.

Comment: It doesn't work. It works if I type `dub run --build plain`. But otherwise unittests are not enabled. I've tried it on two different computers (mac, ubuntu). I start with a plain dub project: `dub init`, add an unittest into `app.d` with a `writeln`, then your lines into `dub.json`.